# Is God cruel if he allows Satan to hurt us?

Tags: nature-of-god, satan, good-and-evil, theodicy

I'm struggling with my faith.  We have had multiple hits that have me wondering why a loving God would allow this to happen?  I'm hear over and over that it's the devil doing it or it is God doing it for a specific reason.  How can a loving God be part of it? It would seem to me that by allowing something to happen it's just as bad as doing it.  For example, a child is drowning.  I may not be legally obligated but I would be morally.  With all these trials, I feel God is cruel.  I know he isn't but I say that with confliction because his actions seem to show otherwise.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your question.  The [mission](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1380) of our site is to answer factual questions about Christianity.  We are not able to answer [more personal questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/255).  We invite you to consult your local church, pastor, priest, mentor, or other trustworthy counselor.  However, the root of your question - how an all-knowing, all-powerful, all-loving God could allow evil to exist has already been addressed on the site.

Comment: If you believe in free will being necessary, then no.